# Firebase realtime stream slow on subscribe

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a Xamarin Android app which has to send a timestamp from one device to all other devices connected to my Firebase database when the user pressed the "Start" button. The subscription is set up like this below:

```
private void SubscribeToFirebaseClient()
        {
            firebase.Child("groups").AsObservable<Group>().Subscribe(d =>
            {
                groups.Add(d.Object.Name); // <--- here
            });
        }
```

It works BUT it takes aprox 30-40 seconds to get to the "<--- here" after changing something in the database? Is there a way to get this to something like 1-2 seconds max?

Im using the free "Spark" package.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Usually the time it takes to load data is a simple division of the amount of data you load and the bandwidth of the device you're loading it on. How much JSON data do you have stored under `firebase.Child("groups")`?

Comment: Only an Id and Name. { Id : 59, Name : "Group 1" }. Don't think this has to take longer than a second.

Comment: And only 3 records*.

Comment: Hmmm.... I'm not sure in that case. If it's only the first load that takes so long, it might be something in establishing the connection. But since I have no idea how the xamarin clients connect to the database, I can't be of much help beyond that. Sorry about that.

Comment: No, unfortunately it's every subscription. I'm using this wrapper if that's some usefull information: https://github.com/rlamasb/Firebase.Xamarin

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @ZaneCampbell No I created a workaround myself using timers...